# how to auto increment id key in Flutter Hive

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, flutter-web, flutter-hive

I'm trying to make a method to add entries in a Hive box but after adding my id key is always null. now I know I can change the key at onPressed() by:

```
 getIt<TodoDatasource>().addTodo(Todo(
                        id: 0,  // <----------------------------- IN QUESTION
                        name: _controlName.text,
                        description: _controlDescription.text,
                        completed: 0, // default
                      ));
```

but doing this will affect the id on my other data sources, SQFLite(which can assign an auto-increment at the id column), and Firebase RTDB(which generates an id for each entry).

what I noticed as well is Hive is also generating an auto-increment on each entry AND based on this GitHub post "[click me!](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/517)", the .add() method returns an int. that's not the case as on my project this returns a Future so can't seem to use that to match my id. is there a solution or a workaround for this problem?

here's the necessary code blocks:

**DataServiceManager class**

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:todo_list1/local_hive_datasource.dart';
import 'package:todo_list1/local_sqlite_datasource.dart';
import 'package:todo_list1/services/todo_datasource.dart';
import 'package:todo_list1/remote_api_datasource.dart';

import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import '../models/todo.dart';

class DataServiceManager implements TodoDatasource {
  late final TodoDatasource _local;
  final TodoDatasource _remote = RemoteApiDatasource();

  DataServiceManager() {
    // if (kIsWeb) {
    //   _local = LocalHiveDatasource();
    // } else {
    //   _local = LocalSQLiteDatasource();
    // }
    _local = LocalHiveDatasource();
  }

  Future<bool> _checkConnectivity() async {
    if (!Platform.isAndroid ||
        !Platform.isWindows ||
        !Platform.isFuchsia ||
        !Platform.isIOS ||
        !Platform.isLinux ||
        !Platform.isMacOS) {
      if (kIsWeb &&
          await Connectivity().checkConnectivity() == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> addTodo(Todo t) async {
    // return await _checkConnectivity()
    //     ? await _remote.addTodo(t)
    //     : await _local.addTodo(t);
    return _local.addTodo(t);
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> updateTodo(Todo t) async {
    // return await _checkConnectivity()
    //     ? await _remote.updateTodo(t)
    //     : await _local.updateTodo(t);
    return _local.updateTodo(t);
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> deleteTodo(Todo t) async {
    // return await _checkConnectivity()
    //     ? await _remote.deleteTodo(t)
    //     : await _local.deleteTodo(t);
    return _local.deleteTodo(t);
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Todo>> getAllTodo() async {
    // return await _checkConnectivity()
    //     ? await _remote.getAllTodo()
    //     : await _local.getAllTodo();
    return _local.getAllTodo();
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> getId(int i) {
    // return await _checkConnectivity()
    //     ? await _remote.getAllTodo()
    //     : await _local.getAllTodo();
    return _local.getId(i);
  }
}
```

**LocalHiveDatasource class**

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

import 'package:todo_list1/models/todo.dart';
import 'package:todo_list1/services/todo_datasource.dart';

class LocalHiveDatasource implements TodoDatasource {
  bool initialised = false;
  int _id = 0; // <----------------------------my workaround

  LocalHiveDatasource() {
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    Hive.registerAdapter(TodoAdapter());
    await Hive.openBox('todos_box');
    initialised = true;
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> addTodo(Todo t) async {

    // MY WORKAROUND
    // can add before pushing to the box but when the app exits,
    // the _id rolls back to 0
    // therefore the instance of entry will not match the id...
    if (t.id == null) {
      _id++;
      t.id = _id;
    }

    // conversion of todos model to map
    final Map<String, dynamic> todoToMap = t.toMap();
    final box = await Hive.openBox('todos_box');
    box.add(todoToMap);
    await box.close();
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> deleteTodo(Todo t) async {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Todo>> getAllTodo() async {
    if (!initialised) return <Todo>[];

    //   opens the box
    Box box = await Hive.openBox('todos_box');

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> retrievedMapdData = box.toMap();

    box.close();

    return List.generate(retrievedMapdData.length, (index) {
      return Todo(
        id: retrievedMapdData[index]['id'],
        name: retrievedMapdData[index]['name'],
        description: retrievedMapdData[index]['description'],
        completed: retrievedMapdData[index]['completed'],
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>> getId(int i) async {
   throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> updateTodo(Todo t) async {
   
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the future giving you a problem? I can sugguest you a way to make that operation synchronous.

Comment: how would you make a Future synchronous?

Comment: You can make the LocalStorage class a singleton with the box object and open the box in the start that is with init method. Now you can use any of the operation using that box and need for await is gone.